# Polymorphic association with AMS using JSON:API specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have been trying save a object who has a polymorphic association, take a look at my `create_params`:

```
module Admin
  class ChatroomsController < AdminController # :nodoc:
    ...

    def create_params
      ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
        params,
        only: [:name, :chatable],
        polymorphic: [:chatable]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

When send to save, the AMS not find a way to resolve the model name:

```
#<NameError: wrong constant name disputes>
```

How I can save objects with polymorphic associations? Thanks.

Comment: Take a loot at my full stack https://gist.github.com/brunowego/33da32291a05a486f512965b2c41134c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the follow fix to solve my issue:

```
module Admin
  class ChatroomsController < AdminController # :nodoc:
    ...

    def create_params
      res = ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(
        params,
        only: [:name, :chatable],
        polymorphic: [:chatable]
      )
      res[:chatable_type] = res[:chatable_type].singularize.capitalize
      res
    end
  end
end
```

AMS [have a pull request to solve](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1615) this.